Are opfibrations stable under pullback?
Fibrations are stable under pullback, which means that if $p$ is a fibration and $F$ is an arbitrary functor in the following diagram, then $p'$ is a fibration as well

Is the same thing true of opfibrations? Or do we have to dualise the pullback as well and say that opfibrations are stable under pushouts?

It's true that opfibrations are stable under pullback. They have a certain right lifting property against the inclusion $0\colon[0]\to[1]$ of the trivial one-object category into the one-arrow category as initial object, which means a pullback of a opfibration will still a right lifting property against this morphism (morphisms with a general right lifting property are always stable under pullback). Moreover, a morphism in $\mathcal{E}\times_\mathcal{B}\mathcal{C}$ is cocartesian over $\mathcal{C}$ iff its projection to $\mathcal{E}$ is cocartesian over $\mathcal{B}$, so our lifts $[1]\to\mathcal{E}\times_\mathcal{B}\mathcal{C}$ will select cocartesian morphisms, showing that $p'$ is an opfibration as well.
Opfibrations are generally not stable under pushout. For instance, there is a pushout diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
[0]\sqcup[0] @>{0\sqcup 1}>> [1]\\
@VVV @VVV\\
[0] @>>> B\mathbb{N}
\end{CD}
$$
where $B\mathbb{N}$ is the category with one object and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ an endomorphism $f^n$ on this object, subject to the composition law $f^n\circ f^{m}=f^{n+m}$. The left-hand map is an opfibration, but the right hand map is not, as it generally does not even have right lifting against $0\colon[0]\to[1]$. (Note that the right-hand map $[1]\to B\mathbb{N}$ sends the morphism $0\to 1$ to $f$.)
